# Oracle database installer in linux [INS-10102] Installer initialization failed

Tags: linux, database, oracle, redhat, database-installation

i am trying to install oracle database in red hat enterprise linux 
and once i run the installer using:

> [oracle@linux database]$ ./runInstaller

the OUI shows the message:

```
[INS-10102] Installer initialization failed.
Cause - An unexpected error occurred while initializing the Installer.  
Action - Contact Oracle Support Services or refer logs  Summary 
 - [INS-10012] Setup driver initialization failed.  
 - no oraInstaller in java.library.path
```

the log file shows this

```
ID: oracle.install.commons.util.exception.AbstractErrorAdvisor:8
oracle.install.commons.base.driver.common.InstallerException: [INS-10102] Installer initialization failed.
    at oracle.install.commons.base.driver.common.Installer.run(Installer.java:534)
    at oracle.install.ivw.common.util.OracleInstaller.run(OracleInstaller.java:133)
    at oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBInstaller.run(DBInstaller.java:139)
    at oracle.install.commons.util.Application.startup(Application.java:1072)
    at oracle.install.commons.flow.FlowApplication.startup(FlowApplication.java:181)
    at oracle.install.commons.flow.FlowApplication.startup(FlowApplication.java:198)
    at oracle.install.commons.base.driver.common.Installer.startup(Installer.java:566)
    at oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBInstaller.startup(DBInstaller.java:127)
    at oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBInstaller.main(DBInstaller.java:165)
Caused by: oracle.install.commons.base.driver.common.SetupDriverException: [INS-10012] Setup driver initialization failed.
    at oracle.install.driver.oui.OUIInstallDriver.load(OUIInstallDriver.java:431)
    at oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBSetupDriver.load(DBSetupDriver.java:289)
    at oracle.install.commons.base.driver.common.Installer.run(Installer.java:516)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no oraInstaller in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.osd.unix.OiipuUnixOps.loadNativeLib(OiipuUnixOps.java:380)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.osd.unix.OiipuUnixOps.<clinit>(OiipuUnixOps.java:128)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicPullSession.createDuplicateStreamsForLog(OiicPullSession.java:5382)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicPullSession.createDuplicateStreams(OiicPullSession.java:5482)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicAPIInstaller.initInstallEnvironment(OiicAPIInstaller.java:506)
    at oracle.install.driver.oui.OUIInstallDriver.load(OUIInstallDriver.java:422)
    ... 10 more
```

[here is a Screen shot for the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4E4o2.png)

Comment: i have installed jdk and set all parameters in
$nano /etc/profile
and then
$source /etc/profile

i also tried to use linux32 before installation and the same error still appears

Answer (score 8):

the problem is solved by installing libnsl.so.1 using :

> #dnf install libnsl

i did understand the issue using this site : 
https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/03/javalangunsatisfiedlinkerror-no-dll-in.html#axzz5hSglKlPs

Comment: This fixed my problem.  Thanks for the post.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, In Centos 8 minimial version and Oracle 12c binaries I tried install `libnsl` package using following `yum` command:

```sh
yum install libnsl
```

NOTE: during my search I found simplified way in installation Oracle dependencies. According to [this](https://www.oracle.com/storage/technologies/ginnydbinstallonlinux.html) link its highly recommended to use oracle pre request installation package in by using following command (in centos):

```sh
yum install oracle-rdbms-server-<your-oracle-version>-preinstall
```

this package helps DBA to install all dependencies before start oracle installation proccess.

Comment: The preinstall is a good idea, but it does not install libnsl.  Installing libnsl fixed orainstaller issues for me when installing Oracle 12.2 RDBMS software on Oracle Linux 8.4

Answer (score 1):

I think you try to install oracle DB server in newer version of OS. It fails to perform prerequisite checks on that system. simply hit the command..

root@ yum install libnsl*